# Unable to Login to Salesforce workbench

Tags: workbench, login-errors

I have signed for a trail licence and want to investigate SOQL function.
When I login into the workbench and select Sandbox it redirects me to test.salesforce.com 
I enter my Salesforce credentials it cannot authenticate.
I have tried chrome and firefox, tried clearing the cookies and cache but no success.
Salesforce login works fine

Answer (score 0):

Trial editions of Salesforce are production instances, not sandboxes. Choose Production and use your trial credentials, and you should be able to log in to Workbench.

Comment: Hi David thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: I am using the credentials uname/pwd and now I am seeing in Production
API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG API Not enabled for this org or partner

Comment: @Grahama Sounds like you've chosen to trial an edition of Salesforce that doesn't provide API access. You'll probably want to discuss that with your AE.

Comment: Hi David, quite odd as I was following a tutorial which said first thing is sign up for a Salesforce Trail licence then follow the script. Looks like there may have been a few prereqs not mentioned.